# Want to run my application as service in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have one application which has no UI. When my phone will boot up, this application should start running automatically. It means there is no need to click any icon. The application will start like a service. How can i do this? Please reply.

This is my code...

public class BlockApplication extends Application {
    int mForegroundProcessId = -1;

```
public BlockApplication() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(mCheckForeground, 1000, 1);                       
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockApplication app = new BlockApplication();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}


TimerTask mCheckForeground = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        int id = getForegroungProcessID();
        if(id != mForegroundProcessId)
        {
            mForegroundProcessId = id;
            String name = getAppNameByProcessId(mForegroundProcessId);
                KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
       inject.post();
                }
    };
};


private int getForegroungProcessID() 
{
    return ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getForegroundProcessId();
}


private String getAppNameByProcessId(int id) 
{
    String result = null;
    ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
    ApplicationDescriptor appDes[] = appMan.getVisibleApplications();
    for (int i = 0; i < appDes.length; i++) 
    {
        if (appMan.getProcessId(appDes[i]) == id) 
        {
            result = appDes[i].getLocalizedName();
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application needs to be a system module.  With the Eclipse plugin you should go to the App Descriptor and check the box that says "Do not display the application icon on the BlackBerry home screen".

Using the BB Ant tools it looks like you should set the systemmodule attribute in the jdp tag to true.

Comment: it is working fine in simulator. But in device it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Blackberry Ant Tools

http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/

In the jdp tag, set these attributes...
runonstartup="true"
startuptier="7"

That will arrange your app to start when the device resets.
If you use the Eclipse plugin there should be similar config somewhere.

Comment: Yes..i did it. Its working. But still my application is showing in the Downloads folder. I dont want to show.